# Ngnix Error/Pterodactyl Error? No clue how to fix

Tags: nginx

Trying to setup a Pterodactyl server using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_Z7GffWwDo&t=168s and I am getting this error code.

```
Mar 01 03:46:28 nugget-mc systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Mar 01 03:46:28 nugget-mc nginx[52886]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/panel.nugget-mc.com.pem": BIO_ne>
Mar 01 03:46:28 nugget-mc nginx[52886]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Mar 01 03:46:28 nugget-mc systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 01 03:46:28 nugget-mc systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 01 03:46:28 nugget-mc systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear? `cannot load certificate`, what can you tell us about that?  Searching for that msg even turns up [some answers here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318580/ssl-certificate-on-nginx-fails-to-load), did that help?

Comment: Does the cert exist, does it have the right perms/ownership, are either of the SELinux issues in the linked question relevant?